# how to return value from a promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function which checks whether a device is online or not. Below is the code.

```js
const ping = require('ping');
export function findDevices(device) {
  try {
    const hosts = [device];
    let result = null;
    hosts.forEach((host) => {
      ping.promise.probe(host)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.alive)
          result = res.alive;
          return {
            Status: result
          }
        });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err, '[ config - findDevices() ]');
    console.error(err);
    return {
      Status: "Failed"
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling this function in a redux action like this:

```js
export function start(device) {
  return dispatch => {
    const status = Connectionstatus.findDevices(device);
    return dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.CONNECTIONSTATUS,
      payload: {
        ConnectionStatus: status
      }
    })
  };
}
```

I am expective the status variable to be either true or false. But i am getting as undefined even though i am returning the value inside then of the promise function. i have tried awaiting this call and still its not working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to return the result outside of `then()` block. This should work.

Comment: i tried that too. it returns null;

Comment: Why you are calling a promise in a loop

Comment: if there are multiple host, i should return the status of the each host. That's why.

Comment: You may want to look at mapping the `hosts` array to all be promises, and resolving them all using `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the case you can do like this

```
const getStatus = async () => {
  try {
    const hosts = [device];
    const promises = [];
    hosts.forEach((host) => {
      promises.push(ping.promise.probe(host));
    });
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    const status = result.map((r) => { return r.alive; });
    return status;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err, '[ config - findDevices() ]');
    return { status: 'Failed' };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what all the vars are, but have you considered using `async/await` to simplify things a bit like this?

```
const getStatus122 = async device => {
  return await Promise.all([device].map(ping.promise.probe))
      .then(({ alive }) => alive)
      .then(Status => ({ Status }))
      .catch(error => {
        logger.error(error, '[ config - findDevices() ]');
        return { Status: 'Failed' };
      })
}
```

More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

With Promises you should inspect the promised result either in `when` or `catch` callback functions. With async/await the code may look a bit simpler. Here is the version with explicit promises.

```
const ping = require('ping');
const Connectionstatus = {
  findDevices: (device) => {
    return ping.promise.probe(device).then((res) => {
      const result = res.alive;
      console.log(result);
      return {
        Status: result,
      };
    }).catch((err) => {
      logger.error(err, '[ config - findDevices() ]');
      console.error(err);
      return {
        Status: "failed"
      }
    });
  }
}
export function start(device) {
  return dispatch => {
    Connectionstatus.
    findDevices(device).
    then((status) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.CONNECTIONSTATUS,
        payload: {
          ConnectionStatus: status
        }
      })
    });
  };
}
```

You may see that error handling moved to the `catch` callback function while the dispatch is done in the `then` callback function. And this is the answer to your question.